# Private static functions in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I create a function that can't be called from outside?

```
var obj = {
    function1: function(){
        alert("function1");
    },
    function2: function(){
        alert("function2...");
        obj.function1();
    }
};
// so how to make this function unaccessible 
obj.function1();
// and you could only call this function
obj.function2();
```

Comment: you want **static function or static method**? do you want it to be static at all? (the example doesn't clarify)

Comment: what is the difference between a static method and function? :S
(btw sorry for using both words)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may want to consider using the [Yahoo Module Pattern](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/). This is a singleton pattern, and the methods are not really static, but it may be what you are looking for:

```
var obj = (function () {

   //"private" variables:
   var myPrivateVar = "I can be accessed only from within obj.";

   //"private" method:
   var myPrivateMethod = function () {
      console.log("I can be accessed only from within obj");
   };

   return {
      myPublicVar: "I'm accessible as obj.myPublicVar",

      myPublicMethod: function () {
         console.log("I'm accessible as obj.myPublicMethod");

         //Within obj, I can access "private" vars and methods:
         console.log(myPrivateVar);
         console.log(myPrivateMethod());
      }
   };
})();
```

You define your private members where `myPrivateVar` and `myPrivateMethod` are defined, and your public members where `myPublicVar` and `myPublicMethod` are defined.

You can simply access the public methods and properties as follows:

```
obj.myPublicMethod();    // Works
obj.myPublicVar;         // Works
obj.myPrivateMethod();   // Doesn't work - private
obj.myPrivateVar;        // Doesn't work - private
```

Comment: myPrivateMethod is not a "static" function. You missed the title.

Comment: I don't believe YAHOO has any rights on the module pattern ;)

Comment: @Crescent: I don't either, but that's how everyone seems to be calling it... Maybe I should have said "the Module Pattern, aka the Yahoo Module Pattern or the YUI Module Pattern" :)

Comment: I believe the pattern originated with Yahoo!'s Douglas Crockford, and was popularised through an article by Eric Miraglia from the YUI team: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

Answer (score 8):

The simple answer is that **you can't do both**. You can create `"private"` methods or `"static"` methods, but you can't create **Private static functions** as in other languages.

The way you can emulate privacy is *closure*:

```
function f() {

  function inner(){}

  return {
    publicFn:  function() {},
    publicFn2: function() {}
  }
}
```

Here because of *closure*, the `inner` function will be created every time you call `f`, and the public functions can acces this `inner` function, but for the outside world `inner` will be *hidden*.

The way you create static methods of an object is simple:

```
function f() {}

f.staticVar = 5;
f.staticFn = function() {};
// or
f.prototype.staticFn = function() {};
```

Here the function object `f` will only have one `staticFn` which has access to *static* variables, but nothing from the *instances*.

Please note that the `prototype` version will be inherited while the first one won't.

So you either make a private method that is not accessing anything from the instances, or you make a static method which you doesn't try to access from the outside.
​

Comment: I guess the question is does javascript have static methods at all. `f.prototype.staticFn` is really just a public instance member of the prototype object. It is only static because, as a member of a different object instance, it doesn't have access to private members of this instance. You could do that with a private method too--just give the prototype instance a private method--it's just that this is not helpful because the child instance can't access the method. So shorter answer is there are no static methods in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a closure,  something along the lines of....

```
var construct = function() {

   var obj = {};

   var method1 = function() {
      alert("method1");
   }

   obj.method2 = function() {
         alert("method2...");
         method1();
   }

   return obj;
}

obj = construct();
```

Then:

`obj.method2` is accessible,  but `obj.method1` doesn't exist for public usage. It can be only accessed using member functions of the class.

Answer (score 1):

> Objects can be produced by *constructors*, which are functions which initialize objects. Constructors provide the features that classes provide in other languages, including static variables and methods.

Read all about it at http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var obj = new function() {
  var method1 = function() { // private }
  this.method2 = function() { // public } 
}

obj.method1(); // not possible
obj.method2(); // possible
```

Note that I also use an anonymous constructor. This is sort of analogous to the Singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want a proxy object containing only the public methods, e.g.

```
var obj = (function() {
  var obj = {
    method1: function(){
      alert("method1");
    },
    method2: function(){
      alert("method2...");
      obj.method1();
    }
  }
  return {
    method2: function() { return obj.method2.apply(obj, arguments) }
  }
})()

// you could only call this function
obj.method2();
// this function inaccessible 
obj.method1();
```

I don't see the point of private methods in javascript. If you don't want people calling a method then don't advertise it. Private methods also make debugging just that bit harder too.

Answer (score 1):

This is how it really should be done.

```
var MyClass = new(function() {
    var privateStaticVariable = '';

    function privateStaticMethod() {

    }

    function construct() {
        var self = this;
        this.publicMethod = function() {};

        function privateMethod() {
            //maybe lest use our private static method
            privateStaticMethod();
        }
    }
    construct.publicStaticVariable = '';
    construct.publicStaticMethod = function() {};
    return construct;
})();

Now lets use it:

    var myClass = new MyClass();.....
MyClass.publicStaticMethod();
MyClass.publicStaticVariable = 'sfdsdf';
myClass.publicMethod();
```

.....

Answer (score 1):

Use `class`. Though some of the features are still not shipped as [it’s at Stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features).

```js
const instance = new (class Alpha {
 static #private_static_method() {
  console.info("I am private and static.");
 }
 static public_static_method() {
  Alpha.#private_static_method();
  console.info("I am public and static.");
 }
 #private_nonstatic_method() {
  console.info("I am private and non-static.");
 }
 public_nonstatic_method() {
  this.#private_nonstatic_method();
  console.info("I am public and non-static.");
 }
});

instance.constructor.public_static_method();
// instance.constructor.#private_static_method(); // impossible
instance.public_nonstatic_method();
// instance.#private_nonstatic_method(); // impossible
```

Comment: Seems like this shipped in all browsers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility